# Telefonisches Vorstellungsgespräch oder Telefoninterview?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich möchte eine Antwort auf die Einladung zu einem "telefonischen Kennenlernen" für eine Bewerbung schreiben. Ich möchte mich erstmal dafür bedanken. Welcher Satz ist besser für diese Situation?

> Vielen Dank für Ihre Einladung zum telefonischen Vorstellungsgespräch.

oder

> Vielen Dank für Ihre Einladung zum Telefoninterview.

Comment: Welches Wort wurde denn bei der Einladung benutzt?

Comment: Wie wär's mit _zum Telefonat_? Oder einfach: _zum Gespräch_? Das ist ein bisschen lockerer. Und geht damit auf den etwas lockereren Tonfall ein, den ich in _telefonisches Kennenlernen_ zu lesen vermeine.

Comment: @infinitezero er hat "einen Termin für ein erstes telefonischen Kennenlernen" benutzt.

Answer (score 4):

Da würde ich aus stilistischen Gründen und einfachheitshalber eher die zweite Variante nehmen, oder einfach "zum Telefongespräch". Oder "Ich bedanke mich für Ihre Einladung und freue mich auf das Telefongespräch mit Ihnen".

Comment: Oder noch einfacher: "Ich freue mich auf das Gespräch." - Solange vorher schon geklärt wurde, dass das Gespräch am Telefon geführt wurde, braucht man das gar nicht nochmals explizit zu sagen.

Answer (score 1):

Da die Einladung bereits erfolgt und daher die Art der Kommunikation bekannt ist, erscheint mir die zweite Variante als besseres Geschäftsdeutsch; professionell-freundlich und nicht übertrieben formell, somit Sinn für Ökonomie vermittelnd, was in einem Vorstellungsgespräch wichtig ist: Einstellungen sind stets zeitaufwändig.

Selbst *Telefonat* oder eifach *Gespräch* sind angemessen. Es ist vom Kontext völlig eindeutig, um welche Art Gespräch es sich handeln wird.

Viel Erfolg übrigens!

Comment: Das mag sich gerade ändern, aber im Deutschen wird ein solches Gespräch eigentlich nicht als Interview bezeichnet.